# how to skip facebook app permissions dialog

Tags: asp.net, facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

Here, I am trying to authenticate user via login and after that I want to skip permissions dialog. But I am unable to achieve this, as it always asking for permissions for app to the user. My intention is if user is not logged into the facebook he/she should be prompted for facebook login and then I will fetch public information by using method Get("/me"). Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

```
public string GetFBAccessToken(string strAppID, string strAppSecret, string strUrl)
{
   // Declaring facebook client type
   var vFB = new FacebookClient();
   string strAccessTok = string.Empty;
   try
   {
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strAppID) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strAppSecret) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(strUrl))
       {
         // Getting login url for facebook
            var loginUrl = vFB.GetLoginUrl(new
                           {
                             client_id = strAppID,
                             client_secret = strAppSecret,
                             redirect_uri = strUrl,
                             response_type = "code",
                             state = "returnUrl",
                             //scope = "",
                             display = "popup"
                           });

         // Redirecting the page to login url
         if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["code"] == null)
         {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(loginUrl.AbsoluteUri);
         }                    

         // Fetching the access token from query string
         if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["code"] != null)
         {
            dynamic result = vFB.Post("oauth/access_token", new
                             {
                               client_id = strAppID,
                               client_secret = strAppSecret,
                               redirect_uri = strUrl,
                               code = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["code"]
                             });
         // Getting access token and storing in a variable
         strAccessTok = result.access_token;
          }
         }
         return strAccessTok;
  } 
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
     //if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["response_type"] == "code")
     //{
     // var fb = new FacebookClient();
     // var details = fb.Get("/me");
     //}

     return strAccessTok;
  }
}
```

Comment: Here, I am able to prompt user for login and then it is moving to permissions dialog immediately. but I want to skip permissions dialog and then accessing public profile info of that particular user.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless to the platform/ language you are using; solution can be as follows.

1. check use's logged in status. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/
2. based on Response status, forcefully call your action (i.e. Log in, Get Permission or any additional action if user is already connected). For Log in check this reference document from FB. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web/

Comment: No, I want this to be done using .net only. I have restriction not to use other languages.

Comment: As I Mentioned regardless to the technology; logic and implementation will remain same. Reference URL will give you an idea how u can follow the steps and what needs to be check and done. I hope that would help

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot skip the Login Dialog.

In fact, it is really important for an APP owner to build a trust relationship with your users. I would recommend you to follow the [Login Best Practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/checklist/) while authenticating the users using your APP.

Comment: But if you see few apps they not at all asking for permissions any more.

Comment: I think that is because they are not asking for extra permission. When someone connects with an app using Facebook Login, the app can access their public profile and friend list — the pieces of information that are visible to everyone. But for other permissions, there will be a permission dialog that'll pop up.

Comment: As you said, in my above code I am no where using extra permissions. Infact I have commented the scope parameter, but still it is asking for public permissions. I want to suppress that too.

Comment: I think what you are trying to skip is the Login Dialog. You cannot skip a Login Dialog. The Login dialog creates a trusted link between you, people using your app and their info. It displays consistent messaging across all devices, enabling apps to request permissions anywhere. There's a separate dialog that'll appear in case of extra permissions. I was talking about that. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I Agree with you, but with my code it is first prompting user for login soon after it is moving to permissions dialog page. I was talking about this scenario. Here, instead I want the user to directly redirect him to my app. So, there will be now more app permissions hurdle in between.

Comment: No. The dialog that is popped up after the login is called login dialog. You cannot skip that if a particular user is not logged in. You can read more about it here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/#loginflows

Comment: here is the link which is explaining about accessing public info directly, http://www.facebook.com/help/334665133281767

Comment: Actually, Facebook does provide this feature but only to limited APP developer companies like Zynga. [This article](http://news.cnet.com/8301-1023_3-57473296-93/facebook-tests-game-play-without-permissions-dialog/) says the same. Even though it's pretty old, but I guess Facebook still doesn't provide this feature to all the developers since it's no where in the Documentation.

Comment: Now does that make sense?